# unable to create Configuration object

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I want to create the following configuration in code.

```
mail{
  signupUrl = "/test/ws/users/signup/"
  signupFrom="Test<mailrobot@test.com>"
  signupReply="Test<noreply@test.comm>"

}
```

I tried the following two ways but am getting errors

Attempt 1. The API (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration$) has a `from` method which takes a `Map`.

```
val mailConfig = Map("signupUrl" -> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
        "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
        "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.comm>")
      val newConfig = Configuration.from(Map("mail"->mailConfig))
      val newConfiguration = Configuration(newConfig)
```

Error

```
Error:(575, 30) overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (underlying: com.typesafe.config.Config)play.api.Configuration <and>
  (data: (String, Any)*)play.api.Configuration
 cannot be applied to (play.api.Configuration)
      val newConfiguration = Configuration(newConfig)
```

Attempt 2 - The API (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration$) has `apply` method which takes `(String,any*)`

```
 val mailConfig = ("signupUrl" -> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
        "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
        "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.comm>")
      val newConfig = ("mail"->mailConfig)
      val newConfiguration = Configuration(newConfig)
```

Error

```
bug in method caller: not valid to create ConfigValue from: ((signupUrl,/test/ws/users/signup/),(signupFrom,Test<mailrobot@test.com>),(signupReply,Test<noreply@test.comm>))
```

Comment: `val newConfiguration = Configuration.from(Map("signupUrl" -> "/test/ws/users/signup/", "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>", "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.comm>"))`. I'm not sure why you're breaking it into three steps.

Comment: The structure I need to follow to access the configuration is `mail.signupUrl`, not just `signupUrl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version works if you just remove the last lin, like:

```
val mailConfig = Map("signupUrl" -> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
        "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
        "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.comm>")
      val newConfig = Configuration.from(Map("mail"->mailConfig))
```

`val newConfig: Configuration = Configuration.from(Map("mail"->mailConfig))`

already returns a Configuration.

If you want to create the Configuration from `key -> value` pairs, you need:

- Put the pairs in a `Seq`
- Transform the `Seq` to `varargs` (`:_*`).

Here the example:

```
val mailConfig = Seq("signupUrl" -> "/test/ws/users/signup/",
      "signupFrom"->"Test<mailrobot@test.com>",
      "signupReply"->"Test<noreply@test.comm>")
    val newConfiguration = Configuration(mailConfig: _*)
```

Comment: I think you are right. Oversight from my side. I'll test.

Comment: Thanks. The `map` one worked. Any clue why I am unable to create the `Configuration` object using `(key,value)`. The `apply` method looks like `def
apply(data: (String, Any)*): Configuration`

Comment: I added this to my answer